# virtual host2 returning data from virtualhost 1ubuntu 22.04 / apache

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

pls. I have on apache server disabled default host (a2dissite 000-default.conf). I had at first installed virtual host1 for 1st domain and all has been working. After I set up 2nd host for 2nd domain (created separate www folder/separate config), standard a2ensite second domain (with apache confirmation and adding to sites-available and also to sites-enabled) after trying second domain it is still redirected to the first virtual host... Have someone some idea what can be wrong?  Thanx a lot...

running: apache, php-fpm, memcached server

Fist virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@demo.domain1.com
    ServerName demo.domain1.com
    ServerAlias demo.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/demo.domain1.com/public_html
    
     <Directory /var/www/demo.domain1.com/public_html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
 
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>   

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =demo.domain1.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and for SSL(created by certbot):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@demo.domain1.com
    ServerName demo.domain1.com
    ServerAlias demo.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/demo.domain1.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.domain1.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.domain1.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

SECOND HOST:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain2.com
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain2.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain2.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

For SSL(created by certbot):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain2.com
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com-0001/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com-0001/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the outputs of `sudo a2query -s` and `sudo apache2ctl -S`